# Regex match if exist or ignore

Tags: regex, logstash

i'm with a throble in regex
Input example:

```
/aaaa/admin.php?file=xpto.js&version=abcd123
/aaaa/admin.php
```

Output 1 -

```
url => /aaaa/admin.php
var => file=xpto.js&version=abcd123
```

Output 2 -

```
url => /aaaa/admin.php
```

i tried `%{NOTSPACE:url}(?:/?%{NOTSPACE:var})` and a others but not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
%{URIPATH:path}(?:%{URIPARAM:param})?
```

The patterns are provided at https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns.

The `%{URIPATH:path}` will match the path, while `(?:%{URIPARAM:param})?` will match 1 or 0 occurrences (due to the optional non-capturing group `(?:...)?`) of the query string.

If you need to get rid of the `?` in the `param`, you may also use

```
(?<path>(?:/[A-Za-z0-9$.+!*'(){},~:;=@#%_-]*)+)(?:\?(?<param>[A-Za-z0-9$.+!*'|(){},~@#%&/=:;_?\[\]-]*))?
```

The output for the `/aaaa/admin.php?file=xpto.js&version=abcd123` input:

```
{
  "path": [
    [
      "/aaaa/admin.php"
    ]
  ],
  "param": [
    [
      "?file=xpto.js&version=abcd123"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The output for `/aaaa/admin.php`:

```
{
  "path": [
    [
      "/aaaa/admin.php"
    ]
  ],
  "param": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I also added a [custom regex](https://regex101.com/r/qnBJer/1) (based on the grok built-in patterns) in case you want to get rid of `?` in the `param` value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex :

```
(%{NOTSPACE:url})(?:\?(%{NOTSPACE:var}))?
```

Demo : http://regexr.com/3f6sm

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```
([^\s?]+)(?:\?(\S+))?
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/aHcvIy/1).

Also, you could just split the url string on `?`